# In Specflow, execute Given step from another Feature

Tags: c#, specflow

I have the following 2 features.

**Feature 1**

```
Feature: Environment data fitting

    Scenario: Deduction of external environment condition
        Given External environment decision records are
            """
            Overcast -> Rainy
            Sun -> Sunny
            No Sun -> Night
            """
        When The data fitting is completed
        Then Show current condition as Rainy, if there is Overcast
        Then Show current condition as Sunny, if there is Sun
        Then Show current condition as Night, if there is No Sun
```

**Feature 2**

```
Feature: Decision making

    Background:
        # Some how load data from 'Given External environment records are'
        #   from 'Feature: Environment data fitting'

    Scenario: Deduction of external environment condition
        Given Accessory decision records are
            """
            Overcast -> Umbrella
            Sun -> Sunglasses
            No Sun -> ElectricTorch
            """
        When The model is trained
        Then Take ElectricTorch, if it is Night
        Then Take Umbrella, if it is Rainy
        Then Take Sunglasses, if it is Sunny
```

Is is possible to execute the `Given` step within `Feature 1` from within `Feature 2`?
For e.g. Execute `Given External environment decision records are` (written within `Feature: Environment data fitting`) whenever the execution of `Feature: Decision making` is in progress.

FYI: I do not want to use the `Given` method from `TechTalk.SpecFlow` as it is *`Obsolete`* now. If we were supposed to use it then it can be used as `Given($"External environment decision records are", data);` but I do not want to write code for this or call this from code. Instead, I wish to write the step using some form of feature or functionality of SpecFlow framewor.

Comment: Why not copy and paste the steps? Gherkin is more concerned with communicating the business use case than it is with reusing code.

Comment: How quickly do these scenarios run?

Comment: How long does it take to run the `Given` step that you want replicated?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Sorry, I did not see your earlier message on 14 Jul. My comment with regard to your particular suggestion on the respective date is: That is something I would prefer as well, but the maintenance problem may occur in the future if many feature files use the same 'Background step'. Reply to your latest 2 comments: Apart from maintenance, I don't find any other problem.